# Façons d'exprimer « ça m'a touché »

Tags: expressions, synonymes

Je suis à la recherche d'un maximum de façons pertinentes d'exprimer « ça m'a touché » dans :

> Merci infiniment pour ton geste de ce midi, ça m'a touché !

Je sais qu'on peut bien sûr ajouter des superlatifs tels que « ça m'a énormément touché », « ça m'a tellement touché... »

Je connais une autre façon quelque peu différente : « ça compte beaucoup pour moi » bien que le geste me procure alors moins d'émotion directe dans ce cas et a peut être plus de « valeur », quoi que pas forcément.

Il y a-t-il d'autres façons d'exprimer le fait qu'un geste d'autrui nous ait touché ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tu peux dire aussi :

> - Merci infiniment pour ton geste de ce midi, j'y ai été très sensible.
> - Merci infiniment pour ton geste de ce midi, il m'est allé droit au cœur !

Comment: Droit au cœur est indubitablement le premier qui me soit venu à l'esprit.

Answer (score 3):

Il existe la possibilité d'utiliser l'expression familière suivante ;

- Ça m'a fait quelque chose.
- Merci infiniment pour ton geste de ce midi, ça m'a  fait quelque chose !

Ce n'est pas très original cependant et ça a l'inconvénient d'avoir deux sens (comme  d'ailleurs « ça m'a touché ») ; selon le premier la personne qui parle est émue sous l'emprise d'un sentiment de gratitude et selon l'autre elle est émue sous l'emprise d'un sentiment de pitié.

On pourrait trouver plus recherchées des formes d'expression comme les suivantes ;

- Merci infiniment pour ton geste de ce midi, tu ne sais pas la gratitude que j'ai éprouvée pour toi !
- … , cela m'a rempli de  reconnaissance pour toi !
- … , ça m'a éveillé d'un coup à ton amitié !
- … , je n'avais de sentiment que pour toi ! (*des amoureux*)

Answer (score 1):

Dans un langage soutenu on utilisera `Cela` plutôt que le mot `Ça`.

Tu peux trouver des synonymes verbaux :

- `Cela m'a ému`
- `Cela m'a fait énormément plaisir`
- `Cela m'a saisi`
- `Cela m'a fait vibrer`
- `Cela m'a enchanté`
- `Cela m'a ravi`
- `Cela m'a réjoui`
- `Cela m'a plu`
- `Cela m'a flatté`

Tu peux également chercher les synonymes du verbe "émouvoir" qui se rapprocheront le plus de ce que tu cherches : [ici](http://www.synonymo.fr/synonyme/%C3%A9mouvoir)

Comment: De la première série seulement les deux premiers conviennent ; de la seconde liste de soit disant synonymes il n'y en a aucun qui  ne change pas l'idée dans « ça m'a touché » et certains sont des remplacements totalement irrationnel; c'est une liste trop longue pour qu'il soit question de synonymes, on ne peut parler que de mots à sens *plus ou moins* connexe, pas de synonymes.